# How to convert list indices into an integer?

Tags: python, python-tesseract, opencv

I am new to python and i am creating a text detection application using python and pytesseract. However i am receiving the follwoing error because i want to remove empty '' but the variable is a list and i am trying to convert it into a dictionary.

I have tried different algorithms to convert it back into a dictionary however it just wont work. Here is the code.

```
`import cv2
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output

pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"


camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _, image = camera.read()
    cv2.imshow("Text detection", image)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("s"):
        cv2.imwrite("Capture.jpg", image)
        break

camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


img = cv2.imread("Capture.jpg")


image_data = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, output_type=Output.DICT)

for i, word, in enumerate(image_data["text"]):
    if word != "":
        x, y, w, h = image_data["left"][i], image_data["top"][i], image_data["width"][i],        image_data["height"][i]
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
        cv2.putText(img, word, (x,y-16), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    # REMOVING '' FROM THE DICTIONARY
    new_list = list(filter(lambda x: x != '', image_data))

if new_list != "":
    # BELOW LINE CAUSES AN ERROR SINCE IT IS NOT A DICTIONARY
    print(new_list["text"])

cv2.imshow("Window", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)`
```

Comment: can u paste a sample of what's inside that list and what u expect to have ?

Comment: Current result - ['', '', '', '', ' ', '', '', '', 'Mandatory', 'documents', '', '', '', ''],                                     Expected result - ['Mandatory', 'documents']

Comment: so u just want to remove zero length strings ?

Comment: Yes, that would be perfect

Comment: i think you couldn't achieve what u wanted  because some of your data has space but looks like an empty string. try to replace space with replace(" ","") then filter empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with the filter statement. Try following this minimal example:

```
image_data = {'text': ['a', '', 'c']}
new_list = list(filter(lambda x: x != '', image_data['text']))
print(new_list)
```

which gives

```
['a', 'c']
```

Also be aware, that you should do the filter outside the for-loop. Currently, you do it inside the for-loop, so the filter will be repeated for each word found by tesseract.